# Cannot install global themes Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

Upon attempting to install a global theme for KDE gives me this error. Couldn't find a definitive fix on google. Again this is on Kubuntu 23.04 fresh install.

```
Installation of /tmp/BtoRJY-com.github.vinceliuice.Layan.tar.gz failed: Could not install dependency: 'kns://aurorae.knsrc/api.kde-look.org/1325238'
```

Similar error for a different theme. Seems to happen on all of them.

```
Installation of /tmp/EOQnIK-Sweet.tar.xz failed: Could not install dependency: 'kns://colorschemes.knsrc/api.kde-look.org/1294011'
```

I appreciate your time